# Unable to find built projects in Drools/KIE Workbench after restarting the machine

Tags: drools, wildfly-10, kie

A small application was implemented on Drools/KIE Workbench. The project was built and task was started and worked fine. Then I stopped the server and restarted the machine. Then I couldn't find the project in project explore. I did the same scenario 2, 3 times, but I got same result. I used wildfly-10.0.0.Final server on windows.
[image]

Comment: did you get any reason/solution for it?

Comment: Sorry !! No, I didn't get any.

Comment: I got my issue, 
1) I was starting server from different location. working directory was getting changed.
2) mvn clean was deleting niogit folder also.